# Print one more parameter with va_args

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a function which implements a custom variant of `printf`.
Does anyone have a clue how I can print out one more parameter with `va_list`? My format is like `"%d some text %s"`. I need `a`, to be printed as first parameter.

```
void func (int a, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    // vprintf(stdout, fmt, a, ap) //Can't do like this :( 
    vfprintf(fmt, a, ap);          //Or like this :( 
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could call `printf("%d", a)` before calling`vprintf` with the rest of the arguments? (But that would mean that the `%d` shouldn't be part of your format, which apparently is the case. Why?)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case, that %d is part of the format.

Comment: This seems like a weird design. Why can't the caller pass `a` like normal?

Comment: The fact that the `%d` is part of the format and the `int` value is not part of the `va_list` is going to make life tricky.  You'll need to parse the format, for example separating it into the part up to (but not including) the second `%`, and use that format with the standalone argument; the remainder of the format is then passed to `vprintf()`.  If you're on a POSIX system and in a multi-threaded program, you might want to use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` on `stdout` to ensure that they're treated as a single unit of output despite the mulit-threading.

Comment: However, you would do best to redesign the interface so that the format string only applies to the `...` (`va_list`) arguments; the fixed argument gets treated separately.  You could look at the FFI (foreign function interface) library; I'm not at all sure it will help, though.  Also, if you're on POSIX and someone passes `"it is %2$s and %1$d things happened"`, you're in deep trouble.

Comment: Yes, I'm on POSIX system. But it is quite old, I even not able to use approaches with __VA_ARGS__ macros as it appears in C99+ standards.

Comment: Curious that you're on such an old system.  However, that simply means you probably won't write code with the `n$` notations in it, so it is one less thing to worry about.  Standard reasons for wanting extra arguments are logging things like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` (presumably not `__func__` if you don't have C99 `__VA_ARGS__` support).  You would probably do best to remove the option of caller-controlled formatting of those fixed arguments, leaving the `fmt` to process just the `...` arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47677355/9062154) to parse format, I've found a simple solution (if `%d` is always first):

```
 void func (int a, char *fmt, ...) {
    char *new_format = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    snprintf(new_format, 10, "%d", a);
    strcat(new_format, (fmt+2));
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vprintf(stdout, new_format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Special Thanks to [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)

Comment: You need to use `strlen()` or something similar rather than just 10 in the call to `malloc()`.  And you need to allow for the size of the number in `a`; if it is a 9-digit number, you need to add more than 9 to the memory allocation.  Integers could be 10 digits plus a sign, so `char *new_format = malloc(strlen(fmt) + 11);` would probably be OK (there are 2 extra characters for the %d that was removed.  Note, though, that people are inventive and the `%d` won't necessarily be first characters in the string.  Be cautious!

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is always printed the same way, it shouldn't be part of the format passed in.  You should instead print it separately.

In the example you gave, change your format string to `"some text %s"`.  Then your function can do this:

```
void func (int a, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;

    // first print the function specific fields
    printf("%d ", a);

    // then the user's format
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments:

#### Redesign the interface

You would do best to redesign the interface so that the format string only applies to the `...` (`va_list`) arguments; the fixed argument gets treated separately.

Standard reasons for wanting extra arguments are logging things like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` (presumably not `__func__` if you don't have C99 `__VA_ARGS__` support — see below). You would probably do best to remove the option of caller-controlled formatting of those fixed arguments, leaving the `fmt` to process just the `...` arguments.

#### If you can't redesign the interface

The fact that the `%d` is part of the format and the `int` value is not part of the `va_list` makes life tricky.

If you cannot, or decline to, change the rules for calling the function, you'll need to parse the format, for example separating it into the part up to (but not including) the second `%`, and use that format with the standalone argument; the remainder of the format is then passed to `vprintf()`. If you're on a POSIX system and in a multi-threaded program, you might want to use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` on stdout to ensure that they're treated as a single unit of output despite the multi-threading.

```
// Using C99 features
void func(int a, char *fmt, ...)
{
    char *p1 = strchr(fmt, '%');
    if (p1 == 0)
    {
        // No conversion specifications. Not puts(); it adds a newline
        fputs(fmt, stdout);
        return;
    }
    char *p2 = strchr(p1 + 1, '%');
    if (p2 == 0)
    {
        // The user invoked func(1, "iteration %d:\n");?
        printf(fmt, a);
        return;
    }
    int buflen = p2 - fmt + 1;
    char buffer[buflen];
    memmove(buffer, fmt, buflen);
    buffer[buflen-1] = '\0';
    // flockfile(stdout);    // Multi-threading
    printf(buffer, a);
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(p2, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    // funlockfile(stdout);  // Multi-threading
}
```

The code cheats; it uses a C99 VLA (variable length array) and also interleaved declarations and statements.  In C90, therefore, you'd probably end up using `malloc()`, or perhaps a fixed size buffer (running risks of overflows), or a hybrid (use a fixed size buffer if the prefix of the format string is small enough to fit, or allocate (and free) if not).

You need to decide on the appropriate error handling strategies.  Note that this isn't bullet-proof code.  Calling `func(a, "%% yield is %d; data is [%s]\n", data);` throws another spanner in the works.  Also, if you're on POSIX and someone passes "it is %2$s and %1$d things happened", you're in deep trouble.

> Yes, I'm on POSIX system. But it is quite old, I am even not able to use approaches with `__VA_ARGS__` macros as it appears in C99+ standards.

It's curious that you're on such an old system. However, that simply means you probably won't write code with the `n$` notations in it, so it is one less thing to worry about.  The multi-threading issue is less likely to be a problem either.  And you can't use the other C99 features that were shown in my sample code.

You could look at the FFI (foreign function interface) library; I'm not at all sure it will help, though.